# Three quadratic equations have positive roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, systems-of-equations

The three quadratic equations $ax^2-2bx+c=0$, $bx^2-2cx+a=0$ and $cx^2-2ax+b=0$ has both roots positive. Then which of the following is/are true

A) $a^2=bc$

B) $b^2=ac$

C) $c^2=ab$

D) $a=b=c$

I assumed $a>0$ so parabola is open upwards and hence it should definitely cut positive $Y $axis as it has both roots positive and hence $c \gt 0$.

Since $c \gt 0$ the third parabola is open upwards and so $b \gt 0$ and finally with same reasoning $a \gt 0$. Now each Discriminant is Non negative so

$$b^2 \ge ac$$

$$c^2 \ge ab$$

$$a^2 \ge bc$$

adding all

$$a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca \ge 0$$ $\implies$

$$(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2 \ge 0$$

if we take equality above i will get $a=b=c$ so fourth option is valid. But how to check whether other options a is/are true

Comment: If $a=b=c$, then all the other options follow.

Comment: ok but that is true when i assume equality. if it is strict inequality?

Comment: By replacing x by 1/x we can see that if any quadratic has a, b and c as it's coefficients then it has positive roots, thus if any of the first three options are true then others are true also which leads is to the fourth option.

Comment: by replacing $x$ by its reciprocal we wont get other equations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the equations have two roots, the leading coefficients must be non-$0\,$, so $abc \ne 0$. Assume WLOG that $a \gt 0\,$ (otherwise use the same argument for $a,b,c \mapsto -a,-b,-c\,$). Since both roots of each equation are positive, it follows by Vieta's relations that $b \gt 0 , c \gt 0\,$ as well, so in the end all three of $a,b,c$ are strictly positive numbers. Now, picking up from where the OP left off:

> $$b^2 \ge ac$$
>   $$c^2 \ge ab$$
>   $$a^2 \ge bc$$

Those are all positive numbers, then multiplying together gives $\,a^2 b^2 c^2 \ge a^2 b^2 c^2\,$. But the latter is in fact an equality, which means that each of the previous three inequalities must be an equality as well, therefore $\,a^2=bc, b^2=ca, c^2=ab\,$. Furthermore, $a^2=bc=\sqrt{ac} \cdot c \implies a=c\,$, so in the end $a=b=c$.

Comment: How do you conclue the fact "But the latter is in fact an equality, which means that each of the previous three inequalities must be an equality as well" ?...

Comment: @Franklin If $p \le q \le r$ and either of the inequalities is strict i.e. $p \lt q$ or $q \lt r$ then it follows that $p \lt r$. Conversely, if $p = r$ then $p = q = r$.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to warn you that the condition you've got, i.e.
$$
(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2 \ge 0
$$
is a *necessary* condition and not a sufficient one. It means that the testing of D against it just ensures that $a,b,c$ *may satisfy* D, but does not ensure that they do. Moreover, it is pretty useless condition as a sum of squares is always non-negative for real numbers, so it has, in fact, no information about $a,b,c$ at all.

We can start by saying that for the three equations to have two root each we need to have $a,b,c$ nonzero. Then we continue by writing down all three solutions
\begin{align}
&\frac{b}{a}\pm\frac{\sqrt{b^2-ac}}{a}\ge 0,\\
&\frac{c}{b}\pm\frac{\sqrt{c^2-ab}}{b}\ge 0,\\
&\frac{a}{c}\pm\frac{\sqrt{a^2-bc}}{c}\ge 0.
\end{align}
Clearly $\frac{b}{a}>0$, $\frac{c}{b}>0$ and $\frac{a}{c}>0$, that is $a,b,c$ have the same sign. Since the roots does not change after multiplying the equations by an arbitrary number, we can assume WLOG that  $a,b,c>0$. Hence, we know that
\begin{align}
b^2-ac\ge 0\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad b^3\ge abc,\\
c^2-ab\ge 0\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad c^3\ge abc,\\
a^2-bc\ge 0\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad a^3\ge abc.\\
\end{align}
Adding together and dividing by $3$ we get
$$
\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{3}\ge abc=\sqrt[3]{a^3b^3c^3}.
$$
The [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#The_inequality) gives then that it is, in fact, equality, therefore $a^3=b^3=c^3$, which implies $a=b=c$, so D is true.

It makes A,B,C to be trivially true as well.